# Researcher 1 runs 1000 regressions, researcher 2 runs only 1, both get same results -- should they make different inferences?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, inference, mathematical-statistics

Imagine a researcher is exploring a dataset and runs 1000 different regressions and he finds one interesting relationship among them.

Now imagine another researcher *with the same data*  runs just 1 regression, and it turns out it's the same one that the other researcher took 1000 regressions to find. Researcher 2 does not know researcher 1.

Should researcher 1 make different inferences than researcher 2? Why? For example, should researcher 1 perform multiple comparisons correction, but researcher 2 should not?

If researcher 2 showed you his single regression first, what inferences would you make? If after that researcher 1 showed you his results, should you change your inference? If so, why should it matter?

**PS 1**: If talking about hypothetical researchers makes the problem abstract, think about this: imagine **you** ran just one regression for your paper, using the best method available. Then another researcher explored 1000 different regressions with the same data, until he found the *exact same regression you ran*. Should you two make different inferences? Is the evidence the same for both cases or not?  Should you change your inference if you knew the other researcher results? How should the public assess the evidence of the two studies?

**PS 2:** please try to be specific and to provide a mathematical/theoretical justification, if possible!

Comment: To be a valid comparison you need to specify all the null and alternative hypotheses. Researcher 2 can only test 1 hypothesis while Researcher 1 probably wants to control thee probability of not make 1 type 1 error out of 1000.  If that is the simultaneous inference that you want to make then you have to make do the p-value adjustment. Researcher 2 has one test and no need for adjustment.  For researcher 1 are you fitting different models to the same data or one model fit for each of 1000 data sets?

Comment: @MichaelChernick there's only one dataset. Researcher 1 fits 1000 models for the same dataset until he finds the one he likes. Researcher 2 fitted only 1.  Both researchers use the same data. So would you say these two researchers would have to conclude different things with the exact same dataset?  Researcher 2 should be rightfully confident of his analysis, while researcher 1 should inflate his p-value/confidence intervals due to multiple comparisons?

Comment: If you followed my argument they do in the sense that only researcher 2 is testing a single hypothesis while researcher 1 is testing 1000 hypotheses and needs to control for all the hypotheses he tested..  It involves two different problems.  What is still vague is what you mean by "finding only one interesting relationship".  Maybe you think you have posed a paradoxical situation.  I don't think that you have.

Comment: @MichaelChernick how is it not a paradox for the exact same data with the exact same model lead to two different conclusions? If you read the two separate papers, what would you conclude?

Comment: Did you read carefully the excellent answer given below? Two different sets of conditions, different hypotheses and possibly different conclusions because the p-values will and should be different.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I did, and I find troubling you think this is correct --- the exact same data, with the exact same model, leading to two different conclusions. See my comments on the answer.

Comment: Look at our comments below.

Comment: There is a waterfall of comments under the answers in which you keep asking trying to find some understanding or state some opinion. Maybe you should be more clear about the issue that you have with this situation. also the enormous ambiguity of the hypothetical case does not really help to let us speak in a common language.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't even matter whether the other researcher did 1000 regressions. In some scientific fields they set tighter $\alpha$ levels for their hypothesis tests, because there are simply many other researchers doing the same work of finding a successful regression (e.g. epidemiology). So if you have a successful result then it depends what you are gonna do with it. If you are in a strict field and sort of create a multiple comparisons situation with your colleagues, alpha << 0.001. If you are a researcher for a company and there is no (publication) bias, alpha = 0.05 or alpha = 0.10 .

Comment: @MartijnWeterings what information do you think would help settling the issue? I can make it more precise, but my view is that *this is an important part of the question*, that is formalizing the information one needs to know to say whether the inference should be the same or not is the interesting part of the question. For instance, your second comment is more towards a formal answer I'm looking for. By the way, I liked your previous answer too, I just think it still quickly dismisses the problem and  as we can see it's not as simple as it looks and it can be properly formalized.

Comment: Indeed it is not a simple problem, it is a complex problem. But the way in which the problem is stated, as if we can make some answer that is both general and formal, just based on 1 vs 1000,  is an oversimplification...

Comment: @MartijnWeterings  my intention was just to say one researcher explored a lot the data set and the other researcher just ran a pre-specified analysis plan, but both reach the same conclusion. I thought the numbers would make it more concrete, but the specific numbers do not matter for the essence of the question.

Comment: ... what I notice is a discrepancy in the way that this problem can be viewed. The information that is necessary would bring the problem down to a less ambiguous problem statement and would streamline the discussion about this problem because people will start speaking about the same issues and aspects. At this moment I am not so sure what your issue is with the stated problem.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I would be happy to make it more precise just tell me where, but I really think there's no need. There are things that are clearly orthogonal to the discussion, such as the things discussed by Adam. The main question here is whether how much one researcher explored the dataset before reaching a conclusion should matter for *your* inference or someone else's and why. While the standard answer is that it does, introducing the researcher that fitted the same model without exploring data shows the fragility of the standard answer, and it's not clear how to conciliate both things.

Comment: In my answer I provided examples how circumstances can have an influence on the provided abstract example. For instance the 1000-test-researchers might be 1) stupid in doing more then necessary or 2) eager to find something. If you could fill in the problem with a more specific described situation then we would be speaking more about the same issues. Your last comment made it already a bit more clear *what* your issue is, but I am still a bit lost in the practical application *where* your ponderings would apply.

Comment: The cases of the astronomers (to which I sadly could not find a link but this is about a shared database), epidemiologists (also shared databases) and psychologists show nice examples. I don't see what is wrong with the behavior in these practical cases when, as outsiders reading other peoples work, we have adaptable inferences based on the gathering of data, analysis of data, and publication of the work (it depends on *all* the circumstances).

Comment: One other simple but important circumstantial difference. It makes a big difference and shows how viewpoint and subjectivity plays a role: when I am either 1) a researcher interested in a hypothesis and looking to find published evidence, or 2) a researcher *not* initially interested in a hypothesis and stumbled across some publication that claims something to be true. then it is different how we see the 1000 regressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my "Bayesian" slant on your question. I think you have described a situation where two people with different prior information should get a different answer/conclusion when given the same dataset. A more blunt/extreme example is suppose that we have a "researcher 1b" who just happens to guess the regression model parameters and conclusions from whatever hypothesis. Running $1000$ regressions is not conceptually too far away from guessing.

What I think is happening...what do we learn about the *researchers prior information* from the above question?
   - researcher 1 probably has a flat prior for the models $P (M_k|I_1)=\frac {1}{1000} $
   - researcher 2 has a sharp prior for the model of interest $P (M_1|I_2) =1$ (assume $M_1$ is the model they both fit)

This is obviously a simplification, but you can see here, we already place a lot more weight on researcher 2's inferences without any data.
But you see, once they both take account of the data, researcher 1's posterior probability for $M_1$ will increase... $P (M_1|DI)>>P (M_1|I) $ (...we know this because it was "better" than $999$ other models...). Researcher 2's posterior can't concentrate anymore, it is already equal to $1$.
What we don't know is *how much* the data supported $M_1$ over the alternatives. 
What we also don't know is how the different models alter the substantive conclusions of researcher 1. For example, suppose all $1000$ models contain a common term, and all $1000$ regression parameters for that variable are significantly greater than $0$ (eg $p-value <10^{-8}$ for all models). Then there is no problem with concluding a significantly positive effect, even though many models were fit.

You also don't say how big the dataset is, and this matters! If you're talking about a dataset with $100$ observations and $10$ covariates/predictors/independent variables, then researcher 1 will probably still be quite uncertain about the model. However, if researcher 1 is using $2,000,000$ observations, this may conclusively determine the model.

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with two people that start with different information, and continue to have different conclusions after seeing the same data. However...seeing the same data will bring them closer together, provided their "model space" overlaps and the data supports this "overlapping region".

Comment: So the fundamental part of your claim is that they should make different inference because they have different priors, and not because how much they "explored the data", correct?

Comment: By the way, how would *you* assess the evidence? Would you care about how many models researcher 1 fitted? If so, why?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily care about the *number* of models fit, but whether or not the model being used is known with a degree of certainty. As I mention briefly, I would want to know if there were reasonable alternatives. For example, if researcher 1 made a "line ball" decision about a variable being dropped/added, I would want to see that mentioned.

Comment: Why would you want to see that mentioned, would that change your prior somehow? Are you using him as proxy for you prior? It's not clear to me the mapping you are making. Why do the reasons of a particular researcher matter for your inference, since it does not affect the data generating process at all?

Comment: @statslearner it does affect the process a lot.. This is why many findings from psychology can not be replicated https://www.nature.com/news/over-half-of-psychology-studies-fail-reproducibility-test-1.18248 . If you get to see a publication from some other researcher's work, then you need to take into account the many others (with similar strategies) may have failed (especially if the analytical technique was not so great). Now, if the researcher *repeats* the experiment more rigorously, then we can be more certain, but until that point not so much. p values are not about truth of hypothesis.

Comment: We are considering the dataset here to be external to the researcher, he did not collect it, and both researchers use the same data. It seems the reasons findings cannot be replicated in psychology is because they just use loose significance thresholds as *the* standard of evidence to judge several crazy hypothesis any reasonable person/scientist would find them a priori ridiculous. Take our case here, if the hypothesis tested in our example is something ridiculous such a power posing, would it matter whether we ran 1 or 1000 regressions?

Comment: The different researchers will (should) have different opinions about the same data. Science is much more subjective than the mathematical engine behind it might make you believe. A hypothesis test never tells you about the credibility of the hypothesis, and only something about the failure rate of the test when the hypothesis is in reality true. (Bayesian inference solves this problem by speaking specifically of probability of the hypothesis but it remains subjective)

Answer (score 8):

The statistical interpretation is much less clear than, what you are asking for, the mathematical treatment.

Mathematics is about clearly defined problems. E.g. rolling a perfect dice, or drawing balls from an urn.

Statistics is applied mathematics where the mathematics provides a guideline but is not the (exact) solution.

In this case it is obvious that circumstances play an important role. If we perform a regression and then calculate (mathematics) some p value to express the strength then what is the interpretation (statistics) and value of the p value?

- **In the case of the 1000 regressions performed by researcher 1** the result is much more weak since this type of situation occurs when we do not really have a clue and are just exploring the data. The p value is just an indication that there *may* be something.

  So the p value is obviously less worth in the regression performed by researcher 1. And if researcher 1 or somebody using the results of researcher 1 would like to do something with the regression then the p value needs to be corrected. *(and if you thought the difference between researcher 1 and researcher 2 was not enough, just think about the multitude of ways
  that researcher 1 can to correct the p value for multiple
  comparisons)*
- **In the case of the single regression performed by researcher 2** the result is much stronger evidence. But that is because the regression does not stand on it's own. We have to include the reasons *why* researcher 2 did only one single regression. This could be because he had good (additional) reasons to already believe that the single regression is a good model for the data.
- The setting of the regressions performed by researcher 1 and 2 is much different, and it is not often that **you encounter both at the same time** for the same problem. If this is the case then either

  - researcher 2 was very lucky

    This is not so uncommon, and we should better correct for this when
    interpreting literature, as well we should improve the publishing of
    the total picture of research. If there are a thousand researchers
    like researcher 2, and we will only see one of them publish a
    success, then because we did not see the failures of the other 999
    researchers we might mistakingly believe we did not have a case like
    researcher 1
  - researcher 1 was not so smart and did an incredibly superfluous search for some regression while he might have possibly known from the start that it should have been that single one, and he could have performed a stronger test.

    For outsiders who are smarter than researcher 1 (do not care about the additional 999 regressions from the start) and read about the work, they might give more strength to the significance of the results, however still not as strong as he would do for the outcome of researcher 2.

    While researcher 1 may have been too conservative when correcting for 999 superfluous additional regressions, we can not ignore the fact that the research was done in a vacuum of knowledge and it is much more likely to find a lucky researcher of the type 1 than the type 2.

An interesting related story: In astronomy, when  they were planning a better instrument to measure the cosmic background with higher precision, there were researchers that argued to only release half the data. This because there is only one shot to gather data. Once all the regressions have been performed by the dozens of different researchers (and because of the incredible variation and creativity of the theorist, there is certainly some fit to every possible, random, bump in the data), there is no possibility to perform a new experiment to verify (that is, unless you are able to generate a whole new universe).

Comment: +1 for @MartijnWeterings as I said in my comments the problem was not well posed mathematically. I got the impression that the OP thought that there is a paradox because because the two researchers would be led to the same model choice but the one doing 1000 regressions is penalized because of the need for a multiple comparison issue.  I don't see this as a paradox at all (not clear but I think the OP did). You gave a very beautifully written and correct answer that also explains intuitively why the two cases are different. I think the OP should give your answer a check!

Comment: @MichaelChernick your comments could have been sufficient to handle the case/problem, but I found it usefull to state an answer with a strong 'statistics $\neq$ mathematics' flavour. Moving away from the necessary *'mathematical/theoretical justification'*, and acknowledging that statistical terms and problems are more vaguely defined than mathematical problems, makes the ambiguity in the question much more clear.

Comment: I completely agree with you .  I hope you could see that I was praising your answer.  I was not seeking to give an answer.  That is why I gave comments to clarify what the OP was saying.  Also I realize it takes a lot more time and thought to give an answer the way you did. That is why I gave an approval to your answer and made an unusual suggestion to the to the OP to check your answer because I think it as complete and well written as there could be.

Comment: Martijn it's not clear what you would suggest. So we have two researchers with the exact same data and model. Are you saying they should conclude different things? And what if they present their papers to you, which one should you believe? How would *you* process the evidence, considering this situation?

Comment: Also, I know this is common practice, but don't you find troubling to say one result is "stronger evidence" than the other, when they are the exact same model and data from the same data generating process? The only thing different is how much a third party looked at the data, and this should not have any relation with the DGP itself or your prior beliefs about the problem. Should researcher 2 analysis be tainted by researcher 1's ignorance, for instance?

Comment: @statslearner what I am suggesting is that we should accept that there is no clear (mathematical) formula for these type of problems. Your case can have many different angles. <\br> If I come across a research by some person that did 1000 different regressions, and corrects for that, then the researcher may have (1) done the right thing when he is searching for a needle in the haystack (2) did more analysis then necessary and was, as a consequence, too conservative in correcting his hypothesis test. (possibly intentional/malicious in order to "proof" something) ....

Comment: @MartijnWeterings why should the intention of the researcher matter for the interpretation of the data? If you're using this as a heuristic, as a layman interpreting an expert result, this is fine. But for a scientist analyzing the data, it seems the researcher's intention should have no bearing on your interpretation of the evidence.

Comment: .... the problem is that we do not *know* the source of the articles that we read, and that we do not have a clear problem such as you state. We encounter multiple researchers that did multiple comparisons and multiple researchers that did single comparisons. If we look at this multiple vs single then we get lost. We should look at the *setting*, *intention* and *circumstances* of the research.

Comment: This is nothing different from the many arguments that have been given over the years as to why p-value adjustment is not necessary.  You should do some more reading on it. You can read pages 158-159 of my book "Bootstrap Methods with Applications to R" coauthored with Robert LaBudde (2011) or a book devoted to multiple comparison such as Westfall and Young (1993) "Resampling-Based Multiple Testing: Examples and Methods for P-Value Adjustment.  Both books published by Wiley. Also Miller (1981) "Simultaneous Statistical Inference" Springer-Verlag and Hsu (1996).

Comment: The intention matters because the 'value of the p value' (pun intended) depends on the user-case. Somebody who evaluates a multitude of comparisons and somebody who evaluates a single regression. Those are different cases and will enter the world (publications) differently. Therefore also people who do not have differentiation in the usecase and just have these two sources, should interpret them differently (a sort of Bayesian analysis, do not look just at the p value in study, but also at the probability for such study to be published).

Comment: Hsu (1996) "Multiple Comparisons:Theory and Methods" Chapman and Hall.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings but more specifically, how would you "pool" the results from the two studies? Notice we are talking about the exact same data and model.

Comment: Mathematically, you *can* pool them. The question is how you should *interpret* it. I believe in Kuhn's theories of science that this is a long and organic process in which opposing researchers are gradually improving their experiments and narrowing down to a more conclusive answer. If you just have those two analyses, than pooling is a bit meaningless (btw pool data, not analyses). Whether researcher 2 analysis is tainted ? It depends. What did researcher 2 conclude? Did he do something revolutionary (which always requires more additional tests) or did he just test a typical theory?

Comment: Pooling is often done to create some average result (average out the bad 'research' or, like a long baseline inferential telescope, magnify multiple tests). But the method of pooling is highly subjective. For me pooling is usefull to create an overview, and not to create a *better* answer (but if done well then those pool overviews allow me to apply my own subjective opinions about the credibility of different data sources in the pool).

Comment: @statslearner note that I gave this third possibility/point in my answer where we might, indeed, encounter both types of analyses at the same time. Either a dumb researcher 1 or a lucky researcher 2. *The circumstances are required in order to interpret this*. Is this a type of research in which researcher 1 was not working effective (doing too many regressions), or a type of research in which researcher 2 was lucky?

Comment: So it seems that you are using the researcher's behavior as a *proxy* for your prior. If the researcher ran 1000 regressions, that would correspond to a low prior to that specific hypothesis. If he ran just 1, this would correspond to a high prior on that hypothesis. If you had the two cases, then you don't know which prior to use.

Comment: It depends on how the data is being gathered and published and what sort of science is being investigated. The question is how to deal with publication bias and whether the 1000 regressions researcher had a positive influence on the availability/publication of a certain dataset (which means that if the investigated effect is weak then we may possibly just be seeing this particular dataset because of a lucky regression). There is no single answer for such general description of a situation and it is not a case of using a simple metric of the number of comparisons made in some analysis.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings why should publication bias matter? Ok, so instead of adding unnecessary noise to the story, just think of this --- *you* ran just one regression for your paper, using the best method available. Another researcher explored 1000 different regressions with the same data, until he found the exact same regression you ran. Should you and the other researcher make different inferences?

Comment: @statslearner Possibly yes, it depends, your problem is underspecified. It isn't so much about the numbers 1000 vs 1. It is about the data gathering and data publication. *If* the other 1000-researcher did not have any influence on this, *then* you do not have to correct for it.  In Bayesian language, his work didn't influence your prior probability of making a positive regression. The data can be treated just like any other data that did not have this 1000-regressions-person working on it. But note, that is only true if the condition that I stated in the beginning of this post is true.

Answer (score 1):

Short story: we don’t have enough information to answer your question because we don’t know anything about the methods used or the data collected.

Long answer...The real question here is whether each researcher is doing:

- rigorous science
- rigorous pseudoscience
- exploration of data
- data dredging or p-hacking

Their methods will determine the strength of the interpretation of their results. This is because some methods are less sound than others.

In rigorous science we develop a hypothesis, identify confounding variables, develop controls for variables outside our hypothesis, plan test methods, plan our analytical methodology, perform tests / collect data, and then analyze data. (Note that the analytical methods are planned before the test occurs). This is the most rigorous because we must accept data and analysis that does not agree with the hypothesis. It isn’t acceptable to change methods after the fact to get something interesting. Any new hypothesis from the findings have to go through the same process again.

In pseudoscience we often take data that is already collected. This is more difficult to use ethically because it is easier to add biases to the results. However, it is still possible to follow the scientific method for ethical analysts. It may be difficult to set up proper controls though and that needs to be researched and noted.

Exploration of data is not based on science. There is no specific hypothesis. There is not a priori evaluation of confounding factors. Also, it is difficult to go back and re-do the analysis using the same data, because the results may be tainted by prior knowledge or modeling and there is no new data to use for validation. A rigorous scientific experiment is recommended to clarify possible relationships found from exploratory analysis.

Data dredging or P-hacking is where an “analyst” performs multiple tests hoping for an unexpected or unknown answer or manipulates the data to get a result. The results may be simple coincidence, may be the result of confounding variable(s), or may not have have meaningful effect size or power.

There are some remedies for each problem, but those remedies have to be carefully evaluated.

Comment: I believe you are adding unnecessary noise to the question. Assume they used the best methods available. The data was not collected by them, but by a statistical agency, so they had no control over data collection. The only difference is how much each researcher explored the data. One of them explored a lot, the other explored only once. Both get the same final model with the same data. Should they make different inferences? And how should that affect *your* inference?

Comment: This isn’t extra noise. Math is math. If the models are identical then they are identical. How you interpret the models is dependent on all of the other variables not included in your problem. If you ignore all of the other context and design or experiments the answer is simple, both models perform equally mathematically and are both scientifically weak.